# FIXED Android app not creating home folder

Tags: android, file, directory

*** FIXED *** I hadn't placed the file creation within the MainActivity's onCreate method

I'm currently programming an Android app, and as such I'm loading it onto my device through packaging the .apk through eclipse and side loading it onto my phone via DropBox. Problem is I'm currently trying to write files, and I've discovered my app it not creating it's "com.*appname*" folder on the interna/external directory, this is something I though was automatically done?

I've tried using such code as;

```
File fileDir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
```

and;

```
File fileDir = new File(getExternalDir(null).getAbsolutePath());
```

Both of which are actually causing the app to crash when it runs. So my question is, is sideloading the app causing it not to create it's "com.*appname*" folder, or do I have to include some specific code?

This is NOT a problem with the manifest file, I am using the correct permissions

Answer (score 0):

Check For permissions in manifest life of application.

If you haven't see any permission added in your application manifest file, add above line

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE">
```